# Two GNU Parallel commands executed on the same machine

Tags: shell, parallelism, gnu-parallel

I'm using GNU Parallel to automatically start a large number of jobs and distribute them on the cores of a machine. One job per core.

```
parallel python3 program.py ::: inputs1*
```

When one set of jobs is about to finish, the remaining jobs only use a subset of the available cores. It would be nice to start the next set of inputs with `parallel` so that they only use the unused cores. So at first a subset of all cores but later, once the previous jobs all finished, all available cores (so I can't use `--jobs`).

If I just start a second command of `parallel`, it starts jobs also for the cores that are already used by the other command. Is there a nice and easy way to avoid that?

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
parallel --load 100% ...
```

It looks at the number of processes currently running and starts a job if there is a core that is idle.

Comment: I doesn't work. On a machine with 12 cores and 5 jobs running on 5 of them from a previous `parallel` command, `parallel --load 100% ...` started 12 new jobs such that more jobs were running than cores were available.

Comment: But where the 5 actually using the CPU? If they were idle, GNU Parallel will ignore them.

Comment: The 5 cores seemed to be fully used on `htop`. Or is there another way to check?